# call a function either from $(document).ready or gender filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a function called `createtable` that takes `gender` as a parameter. When the fist time page loads I want the `$(document).ready` to fire that function with a default gender value and when later I select the gender filter, I want the `createtable` function to be executed with that value. Below is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var gender = 'all';

  $('.ranges ul li').click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle span").text($(this).text());
    $('.ranges ul li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    switch ($(this).text()) {
      case 'All':
        gender = 'all';
        break;
      case 'Female':
        gender = 'f';
        break;
      case 'Male':
        gender = 'm';
        break;
      case 'Not Specified':
        gender = 'none';
        break;
      default:
        gender = 'all'
    }
    createtable(gender);
  });

  createtable(gender);
});
```

`createtable` is a function defined in the `$(document).ready` scope itself. The problem is that first time when page loads, the `createtable` function gets executed once, but when I change the gender using filter it gets executed twice.

Comment: Do you have nested `li` elements? That's the only reason I could see why your click handler would be fired twice.

Answer (score 0):

try to stop event propagtion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var gender = 'all';

  $('.ranges ul li').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); //stop bubble up
    $(".dropdown-toggle span").text($(this).text());
    $('.ranges ul li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    switch ($(this).text()) {
      case 'All':
        gender = 'all';
        break;
      case 'Female':
        gender = 'f';
        break;
      case 'Male':
        gender = 'm';
        break;
      case 'Not Specified':
        gender = 'none';
        break;
      default:
        gender = 'all'
    }
    createtable(gender);
  });

  createtable(gender);
});
```